# ¿Como numerar las linea de texto en un QtextEdit desde QtDesigner?

Tags: python-3.x, qt, pyqt5, interfaz-gráfica

estoy manejando PyQt desde la herramienta el Qt Designer, por lo no programo la interfaz grafica desde el código puro.

Mi pregunta es, si tengo el siguiente texto en un QtextEdit

```
linea 1
linea 2
linea 3
```

¿Como logro ver  a la par el numero de linea?
Lo que busco es que sea similar a un editor de código
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero no estoy seguro de si eso se puede hacer desde Qt Designer o voy a tener que programar la clase para el editor en si.
Gracias

Comment: Disculpa una pregunta, encontraste solucion a tu problema ? que me podas compartir.

Comment: @PabloOsuna  puedo compartir contigo, mira mi respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Si programa la GUI desde un código limpio, se ve así:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QRect, QSize
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QPlainTextEdit, QTextEdit,
            QMainWindow, QAction, qApp, QApplication)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor, QPainter, QTextFormat, QKeySequence, QFont


class LineNumberArea(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, editor):
        super().__init__(editor)
        self.codeEditor = editor

    def sizeHint(self):
        return QSize(self.editor.lineNumberAreaWidth(), 0)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        self.codeEditor.lineNumberAreaPaintEvent(event)


class PlainTextEdit(QPlainTextEdit):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.lineNumberArea = LineNumberArea(self)

        self.blockCountChanged.connect(self.updateLineNumberAreaWidth)
        self.updateRequest.connect(self.updateLineNumberArea)
        self.cursorPositionChanged.connect(self.highlightCurrentLine)
        self.updateLineNumberAreaWidth(0)

    def lineNumberAreaWidth(self):
        digits = 1
        max_value = max(1, self.blockCount())
        while max_value >= 10:
            max_value /= 10
            digits += 1
        space = 3 + self.fontMetrics().width('9') * digits
        return space

    def updateLineNumberAreaWidth(self, _):
        self.setViewportMargins(self.lineNumberAreaWidth(), 0, 0, 0)

    def updateLineNumberArea(self, rect, dy):
        if dy:
            self.lineNumberArea.scroll(0, dy)
        else:
            self.lineNumberArea.update(0, rect.y(), self.lineNumberArea.width(), rect.height())
        if rect.contains(self.viewport().rect()):
            self.updateLineNumberAreaWidth(0)

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        super().resizeEvent(event)
        cr = self.contentsRect()
        self.lineNumberArea.setGeometry(QRect(cr.left(), cr.top(), self.lineNumberAreaWidth(), cr.height()))

    def highlightCurrentLine(self):
        extraSelections = []
        if not self.isReadOnly():
            selection = QTextEdit.ExtraSelection()
            lineColor = QColor(Qt.yellow).lighter(160)
            selection.format.setBackground(lineColor)
            selection.format.setProperty(QTextFormat.FullWidthSelection, True)
            selection.cursor = self.textCursor()
            selection.cursor.clearSelection()
            extraSelections.append(selection)
        self.setExtraSelections(extraSelections)

    def lineNumberAreaPaintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self.lineNumberArea)
        painter.fillRect(event.rect(), Qt.lightGray)
        block = self.firstVisibleBlock()
        blockNumber = block.blockNumber()
        top = self.blockBoundingGeometry(block).translated(self.contentOffset()).top()
        bottom = top + self.blockBoundingRect(block).height()
        height = self.fontMetrics().height()

        while block.isValid() and (top <= event.rect().bottom()):
            if block.isVisible() and (bottom >= event.rect().top()):
                number = str(blockNumber + 1)
                painter.setPen(Qt.black)
                painter.drawText(0, top, self.lineNumberArea.width(), height, Qt.AlignRight, number)

            block = block.next()
            top = bottom
            bottom = top + self.blockBoundingRect(block).height()
            blockNumber += 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setFont(QFont("Times", 12, QFont.Bold))
    codeEditor = PlainTextEdit()
    codeEditor.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]